# Map entity to another one mapped by a different entity manager

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm developing a Symfony application. I need to keep two entity managers, both of them with the same connection, one (A) for my entities and one (B) for entities that are managed by other applications. For the entities managed by B I can only make CRUD actions on them but cannot update phisically the table in the database.

For this reason I created two entity managers, so there is no risk with wrong updating. I know, these entities must match with the one in database but that cannot be Symfony to perform this action directly.

Now I'd need to map one entity from A to one entity of B. I've googled a lot to achieve this, but I didn't find anything. Well, I saw that I should map the entity of B inside A, but I cannot do this.

This is how the doctrine is configured:

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
              connection: default
              mappings:
                  AppBundle: ~
                  FOSUserBundle: ~
                  FOSOAuthServerBundle: ~
        no_update:
              connection: default
              mappings:
                  AppNoUpdateBundle: ~
```

Do you know other ways to achieve this?

Thank you very much

Comment: When you can not update the entities you are not doing CRUD operations! ;-) Have you considered [marking your entities as read only](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/improving-performance.html#read-only-entities)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I mean, I can make select insert etc but not alter tables. It is up to me to maintain the class updated (unfortunately). The readonly is really nice and I didn't know about it, but it performs alter table queries... If there is a way to skip the entity while executing the `doctrine:schema:update -f` that would be perfect